# How to retrieve the data from the JTable cell and not the data from the table model?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, renderer

I have this renderer that changes the value of JTable cell.

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    String label = value.toString();
    if(label.equals("-")
        label = "error";
    setValue(label);

    return this;
}
```

In the table's data model, data in row 1, column 2 is "-"
In the JTable GUI, data in at row 1, column 2 is "error"

This code prints the value in data model: "-".

```
System.out.println(table.getValueAt(1, 2).toString());
```

Is there any simple way to retrieve the value "error"?

Comment: I have this renderer that changes the value of JTable cell. - don't do that in XxxRenderer, this is job for XxxTableModel, better and without any side_effects  to implement this logics to code (before is executed) that fills, save data to the XxxTableModel,

Comment: XxxRenderer is invoked from every Mouse & Key Events over JTables view, rest <50pct from methods implemented in related APIs, Listeners added to JTable (API or programatically) and its notifiers

Comment: btw: fortunately the snippet above doesn't do the atrocity that you describe :-) Assuming the containing class extends DefaultTableCellRenderer, it simply sets the _label's text_ to value.

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks for pointing that out. I'm having second thoughts whether to modify the table model or the label's text.

Comment: @kleopatra yes that class extends DefaultTableCellRenderer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your renderer extends `JLabel`

```
((JLabel)table.getCellRenderer(row, column)
.getTableCellRendererComponent(pass all the params here)).getText();
```

Comment: @kleopatra thank you:) It was just a guess based on common practice.

Comment: Problem here: in getTableCellRendererComponent() wee need to pass the param "value" before. That is the value we are searching for. So this is not working for me.